# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax

I am sending the form data to web api controller in asp.net mvc but my ajax request not hitting the controller every time i got the above error kindly tell me how to send request with files in ajax in asp.net mvc to web api controller

```
$(document).on("submit", ".SignupForm", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(".SignupForm"));
    formData.append($('#imageFile')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/Countries',
        type:'POST',
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (data, status, abc) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(abc);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Easy's answer is right, if you don't understand his answer there is what you want.

```
formData.append('chooseAName', $('#imageFile')[0].files[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

See this: (apparently you must add argument)

> SyntaxEDIT There are two versions of this method: a two and a three
>   parameter version:
>
> formData.append(name, value); formData.append(name, value, filename);
>   Parameters
>
> name The name of the field whose data is contained in value. value The
>   field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses
>   such as File). filename Optional The filename reported to the server
>   (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter.
>   The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename
>   for File objects is the file's filename.
>   ExampleEDIT The following line creates an empty FormData object:
>
> var formData = new FormData(); **// Currently empty You can add
>   key/value pairs to this using FormData.append:**
>
> **formData.append('username', 'Chris'); formData.append('userpic',
>   myFileInput.files[0], 'chris.jpg');** As with regular form data, you can
>   append multiple values with the same name. For example (and being
>   compatible with PHP's naming conventions by adding [] to the name):
>
> formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput1.files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
>   formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput2.files[0], 'chris2.jpg');
>   This technique makes it simpler to process multi-file uploads because
>   the resultant data structure is more conducive to looping.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: Kindly give me some demo where i can found the runing code